# Rails 3: filter from assosiated records returned by has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

I'm trying to explain something quite complex. Perhaps more complex to say than do. I have "events". These events belong to "venues". So venues **have_many** events in the venues model.

But events are complicated and have scopes to determine if the event is past, present or future. The scope which gets the correct events (future or present only) is:

```
scope :not_over_or_in_progress, lambda { where("start_date < ? AND end_date > ? OR end_date IS NULL AND start_date > ? OR end_date IS NOT NULL AND start_date > ? OR start_date = ? OR end_date = ?", Date.today,  Date.today, Date.today, Date.today,  Date.today,  Date.today) }

scope :valid, (not_over_or_in_progress.active).order("start_date ASC")
```

Not very pretty but works ok. Now when I show a venue, I can get the associated events with:

```
<% @venue.events.each do |event| %>
  <li><%= event.title %> - (<%= event.event_status? %>)</li>
<% end %>
```

I get all events, whether they are past, present or future. It's not returning @events.valid, but @events.all (all of them). **I would like to get the associated events filtered by my scope (valid) of by my helper (event_status?). Is that possible?**

I get some helpers I did to determine if the event is over. That's what event_status? is for. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to change:

```
<% @venue.events.each do |event| %>
  <li><%= event.title %> - (<%= event.event_status? %>)</li>
<% end %>
```

into:

```
<% @venue.events.valid.each do |event| %>
  <li><%= event.title %> - (<%= event.event_status? %>)</li>
<% end %>
```

You also might like to know that if you use the `meta-where` gem, then you can change your scope from:

```
scope :not_over_or_in_progress, lambda { where("start_date < ? AND end_date > ? OR end_date IS NULL AND start_date > ? OR end_date IS NOT NULL AND start_date > ? OR start_date = ? OR end_date = ?", Date.today,  Date.today, Date.today, Date.today,  Date.today,  Date.today) }
```

into:

```
scope :not_over, lambda { where(:start_date <= Date.today, :end_data >= Date.today) | where(:start_date = Date.today, :end_date => nil)}
```

Put this in an initializer

```
MetaWhere.operator_overload!
```

(much cleaner?)

Comment: Super awesome answer!! +100 Thanks a lot. I'm loving rails and the community so far. I'll try that gem, cause my scopes are ugly! Also, should think of having @venue.events.valid as part of the venues controller or model to be more MVC?

Comment: @ryan actually using meta-where you can do that kind of stuff.